# Frequency analysis and classification of sound signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, frequency-analysis

I am having some problems with a task in signal processing. The idea is to analyze a sound signal, containing the sound of someone dialing a phone number on an old-fashioned analog phone line. The function **dtmf_84125P** takes the filename of the signal as input, reads it and should return a string containing the dialed number, e.g.

```
number = dtmf_84125P('dtmf_84125P.wav')
```

Then for example, number = '0504063452'.

What I have attempted to do is shown below:

```
function [output_seq] = dtmf_84125P(input_file)
%dtmf_84125P Decodes DTMF-signal to numbers.
%   input_file: string with filename of DTMF-signal
%   output_seq: string with decoded numbers from the DTMF-signal
%
%   Mikael Eriksson
%   84125P
%   mikael.eriksson@aalto.fi

[x,fs] = wavread(input_file);
N = 205;    % N-point Fourier transform
L = 5; %Frame length for energy calculations
MINPEAK = 20;
f = linspace(0,fs/2,N);
f2 = linspace(0,fs/2,ceil(N/L));
soundlength = 0.07;     
breaklength = 0.04; 
%soundsc(x)
output_seq = [];
harm1 = [697,770,852,941];
harm2 = [1209,1336,1477];
%           1209 Hz     1336 Hz     1477 Hz
%   697 Hz  1           2           3       
%   770 Hz  4           5           6 
%   852 Hz  7           8           9
%   941 Hz              0    


%Test
% t = linspace(0,1,8000);
% fr1 = 500;
% fr2 = 900;
% x = 5*sin(2*pi*fr1*t)+2*sin(2*pi*fr2*t);
% soundsc(x) 

for i = 1:round((soundlength+breaklength)*fs):length(x)-round((soundlength+breaklength)*fs)

    %Choose subset of signal i time-domain, moving the window forward in
    %every loop. Perform Fourier-transform on this subsignal...
    num = '';
    s = x(i:i+round((soundlength+breaklength)*fs)-1);
    S = fft(s,N);
    S_abs = abs(S);        
    E = zeros(ceil(N/L),1);
    ind  = 0;

    %...and calculate its energy.
    for k = 1 : L : N-L
        ind = ind+1;
        E(ind) = sum(S_abs(k:k+L-1).^2)/L;
    end;

   %Plot the Fourier-transform and the energy of the signal in the current
   %window.
   plot(f,S_abs,f2,E,'ro')
   soundsc(s)
   %pause(0.2)

    % See if there are energy peaks at certain frequencies. First find all
    % peaks, then find the two different frequerencies, and finally the
    % number of this frequency-pair.
    [pks,locs] = findpeaks(E(2:end),'MINPEAKHEIGHT', min([MINPEAK, 0.99*max(E(2:end))]));
    freq = f2(locs);

    if length(pks) >= 2
        [amplitude_sorted, index] = sort(pks,'descend');
        freq = freq(index);

        if freq(1) < freq(2) 
            [tmp,ind] = min(abs(harm1-freq(1)));
            freq1 = harm1(ind);
            [tmp,ind] = min(abs(harm2-freq(2)));
            freq2 = harm2(ind);
        else
            [tmp,ind] = min(abs(harm1-freq(2)));
            freq1 = harm1(ind);
            [tmp,ind] = min(abs(harm2-freq(1)));
            freq2 = harm2(ind);
        end

        switch freq1
            case 697
                switch freq2
                    case 1209
                        num = '1';                
                    case 1336
                        num = '2';
                    case 1477
                        num = '3';
                end
            case 770
                switch freq2
                    case 1209
                        num = '4';                
                    case 1336
                        num = '5';
                    case 1477
                        num = '6';
                end
            case 852
                switch freq2
                    case 1209
                        num = '7';                
                    case 1336
                        num = '8';
                    case 1477
                        num = '9';
                end
        end
    elseif length(pks) == 1
        num = '0';
    end

    % If a number was dialed in this window of the signal and this was
    % detected, add it to the output sequence.
    if num ~= ''
        output_seq = [output_seq,num];
    end          

end

end
```

So the idea is to analyze the signal in small parts, knowing that there will never be more than one dialed number in a window of 0.07+0.04 s. So I loop through the original signal x, and each time the analyzed part of the signal is of this length and named s. I Fourier-transform it to S, and analyze the energy at different points of the spectrum. If there are peaks of significant energy I attempt to classify these peaks to a number according to the table given as a comment in the beginning of the code.

However, the output this code generates is only an empty string. I am suspicious about the spectrum, which I plot in each window, since it often contains 4 peaks instead of 2. Additionally, the low peaks seem to be at slightly too low frequencies, and the high peaks at much too high frequencies compared with the table. I am actually not sure if this signal energy way of doing things is the best way to go, so I am open to suggestions, but having implemented the code as such, it would of course be convenient if it is possible to use it. It would save me at least some time.

I am not going to make this question any longer now, but please do not hesitate to ask if you need additional information. Thank you for your help!

-Mikael

Comment: That is too much code for anyone to reasonably analyse here.  Please do some debugging first, to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Also it looks like you've forgotten to apply a window function prior to your FFT.

Comment: I realized that the table may be incorrect since the spectrum frequencies are different. The table was not given in the task, but I took it straight from another task in the same course on this subject. I e-mailed the teacher about it and await his answer, if I still can't figure it out after that I'll break it down into smaller parts and ask again. The problem is, I really have debugged it, but I can't be sure where it actually goes wrong.

Comment: Paul R, can you elaborate on that? I am new to signal processing.

Comment: @mkerikss: there are already quite a few good questions and answers right here on SO which cover spectral analysis, window functions, etc. Wikipedia also has good pages on [window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) and [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage).